# Драйвер видеокарты есть, но игры его не видят

Tags: windows, windows-10, драйвер, видеокарта

Установил 10-ку на свой ThinkPad. Обновил все дрова, НО

При запуске игр и тп вылетает ошибка видеокарты. Полез в диспетчер устройств. В свойствах видеоустройства написано "Для данного устройства НЕ установлены драйвера", иду обновлять: "Наиболее подходящие драйвера для этого устройства уже установлены". А один фиг, ничего не работает.

Comment: Ну а на сайте производителя нету страницы с дровами конкретно под твою железку? У них там по сервис коду можно было раньше искать.

Answer (score 0):

Ставить вручную, без всяких драйвер-мастеров и т.д. Ручками, как это было раньше)

Хотя, что должен сказать, что такой проблемы быть не должно, и может всё же стоит, допустим, устройство перезагрузить и подобные не хитрые манипуляции сделать

Answer (score 0):

**Поставьте драйвера в ручную, так называемый "Мастер установки Драйверов" не всегда установит свежий драйвер, или вообще его найдет, как в вашем случае**

Ссылки для установки видеодрайверов:

1. [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=ru)
2. [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support)
3. [Intel](https://www.intel.ru/content/www/ru/ru/download-center/home.html)

Comment: Скачал я драйвера, ставлю вручную, пишет то же самое. Решил удалить устройство с драйверами. Теперь у меня не AMD, а "Базовый видеоадаптер Microsoft" и дисплей 640х480 как гвоздями прибит! И при попытке обновить, пишет то же самое: "Наиболее подходящие драйвера уже установлены"

Comment: Может проблема в самой ОС?